# Expected value of product of an ito integral and a random variable

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I want to compute 
$$E[\int_0^t W_r dr \int_0^s W_r^2 dW_r].$$
Here $t,s$ are arbitrary.
I have thought about this a lot but not sure how to proceed.  I tried to apply Ito's formula to one of the factors in the product, but that did not seem to help.  Any idea will be appreciated!

Comment: $$\int_0^tW_rdr=\int_0^t(t-r)dW_r\implies E\left(\int_0^tW_rdr\int_0^sW_r^2dW_r\right)=\int_0^{\min(s,t)}(t-r)E(W_r^2)dr={}{}{}\ldots$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by using Ito's formula to write 
$$
\int_0^s W^2_r\,dW_r={1\over 3}W^3_s-\int_0^s W_u\,du.
$$

Comment: I know how to compute $E[\int_0^t W_r dr \int_0^s W_u du]$, but not sure how to deal with $E[W_s^3/3 \int_0^t W_r dr]$...

Comment: Swap expectation and integration: $\int_0^t E[W_s^3W_r]\,dr$. Now split the integral into $r\le s$ and $r>s$.  There might be a couple of cases to worry about, depending on which of $s$ and $t$ is bigger.